# How to create matrix on Month basis using multiple dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have below mentioned eight dataframe:

```
DF_1

Date                    ID
2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-08 19:55:45     AB-5
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-10 14:15:16     AB-8
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9
2017-03-28 21:45:24     AB-10

DF_2

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-08 19:55:45     AB-5
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-10 14:15:16     AB-8
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_3

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-08 19:55:45     AB-5
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-10 14:15:16     AB-8
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_4

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-08 19:55:45     AB-5
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-10 14:15:16     AB-8
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_5

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-10 14:15:16     AB-8
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_6

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-01-15 18:12:20     AB-3
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-03-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-03-25 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_7

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-01-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-02-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-02-10 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-04-02 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-05-20 19:40:11     AB-9

DF_8

2017-01-01 12:04:01     AB-1
2017-02-12 22:15:21     AB-2
2017-03-02 17:05:45     AB-4
2017-03-15 13:04:09     AB-6
2017-04-05 20:22:22     AB-7
2017-05-25 19:40:11     AB-9
```

Using above dataframe i want to create below mentioned matrix by month, where we should consider date and month of only first dataframe `DF_1` for rest of the other data frame we match only `ID`.

**Required Output**

```
Month   DF_1  DF_2  DF_3  DF_4  DF_5  DF_6  DF_7  DF_8
Jan-17  3     3     3     3     3     3     2     2    
Feb-17  3     3     3     3     2     2     2     2
Mar-17  4     3     3     3     3     2     2     2
```

Comment: So have you tried anything? Please include any attempts you've made, and any warnings/errors you get from it.

Comment: @r2evans Yes I have tried to create a vector for this using `merge` based on `ID` and than taking `nrow` but couldn't create the desired vector.

Comment: What did you create? The point of that question was for you to *show* your code, not just talk about it. If the problem is a simple syntax error in your code, we can give just what is necessary for it to work without unnecessarily giving you a completely different implementation. But I also ask because SO is not a "code this for free" service; though it does happen periodically, it is not fair for you to assume that you can provide just your specifications and retrieve an answer.

Comment: @r2evans I have tried to create the vector but couldn't finalize the final approach, and yes the motive of asking the question is that it will always be there on SO and help someone who is struggling for the same kind of dataset. I am trying to restructure the code and will share here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to place the datasets in a `list`

```
lst <- mget(paste0("DF_", 1:8))
```

In case, the 'Date' is not a Datetime class, do the conversion

```
lst <- lapply(lst, transform, Date = as.POSIXct(Date))
```

`split` the 'ID' of the first dataset by the extracted 'month-year' in 'Date' column ('lst1'), loop through the `list`, check how many of 'ID' are there in each of 'lst1' elements

```
lst1 <- split(DF_1$ID, format(DF_1$Date, "%b-%y"))
```

Or use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
lst1 <- split(DF_1$ID, zoo::as.yearmon(DF_1$Date))
sapply(lst, function(x) sapply(lst1, function(y) sum(x$ID %in% y)))
#          DF_1 DF_2 DF_3 DF_4 DF_5 DF_6 DF_7 DF_8
#Jan 2017    3    3    3    3    3    3    2    2
#Feb 2017    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    2
#Mar 2017    4    3    3    3    3    2    2    2
```

---

Or another option is to create a named `vector`, then loop through the `list`, match with 'ID' column, and get the `table`

```
nm1 <- setNames(as.yearmon(DF_1$Date), DF_1$ID)
sapply(lst, function(x) table(nm1[x$ID]))
#         DF_1 DF_2 DF_3 DF_4 DF_5 DF_6 DF_7 DF_8
#Jan 2017    3    3    3    3    3    3    2    2
#Feb 2017    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    2
#Mar 2017    4    3    3    3    3    2    2    2
```

If some cases are missing, then convert to `factor` with `levels` specified.  For testing, removing some of the rows of 'DF_8'

```
lst$DF_8 <- lst$DF_8[1:2,]
sapply(lst, function(x) table(factor(nm1[x$ID], levels = as.character(unique(nm1)))))
#         DF_1 DF_2 DF_3 DF_4 DF_5 DF_6 DF_7 DF_8
#Jan 2017    3    3    3    3    3    3    2    2
#Feb 2017    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    0
#Mar 2017    4    3    3    3    3    2    2    0
```

Comment: How will i get the `nrow` using `ID`.

Comment: since my dataset is very big, i don't think converting it in list would work/

Comment: @Rahulshah  Based on the expected, I guess you wanted to know how many 'Jan-17', 'Feb-17' etc are there in each dataset?

Comment: @Rahulshah  how big is the dataset?

Comment: No i'm considering 'Jan-17', 'Feb-17' etc. based on only first dataframe than i'm using `ID` to match and get the required numbers from other dataframe.

Comment: @Rahulshah  It is not clear to me.  In the expected output, there is no reference to ID

Comment: Approximately one dataframe is containing around 0.5 million rows.

Comment: @Rahulshah  That is okay for 8 datasets

Comment: You are right, in the expected output there is no reference of `ID` because it give me count based on Month considering first dateframe to all other seven dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166621/discussion-between-rahul-shah-and-akrun).

Comment: @Rahulshah  Why do you have 2 for Feb-17 DF_8 count where as the input have only 1 occurence of Feb-17, similary for Jan-17

Comment: because  `ID` 'AB-4' and 'AB-6' belong to 'Feb-17' in First Data frame.

Comment: I think you got my question now i am taking `Month` from dataframe one matching `ID` of those month in other dataframe and taking count.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 9` because for one month i don't have any row in `DF_8` in that case it should be show as `0`.

Comment: @Rahulshah  Updated the post

Comment: actually i have missed this point in my question that if for any month if we don;t have rows in any dataframe other than `DF_` than it should be `0`.

Comment: getting this error: `Error in factor(nm1[x$ID], labels = unique(nm1)) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 10 should be 1 or 9`

Comment: @Rahulshah  Sorry, I should have changed the `levels`.  Can you test it now

Comment: I want to show `0` where i don't have value for any particular month other than `DF_1`.

Comment: @Rahulshah  I got your comment earlier, it was a bug as I didn't test it earlier.  It should work now as I have changed your example by removing the rows in 'DF_8'

Comment: Now it worked but don't know why Month is coming in uneven format, i.e Jun-17, Jan-17, Mar-17, May-17 etc,

Comment: @Rahulshah  For that you need to change the `levels = ` in the order you want to appear.  Here i used `unique(as.character(nm1))`.  Check the order of `unique(nm1)` and change it to your custom order

Comment: @Rahulshah Here is what i meant.  when you take `unique(nm1)`, it have an order. and that order is maintained in the table because we are converting to `factor` with levels in that order.  Suppose, you want the order of the yearmon (it is a year mon class), so , do `levels = as.character(sort(unique(nm1)))`

Comment: Thank a lot...:) can you just suggest me how to give first column  name as `Month` in the final output.

Comment: @Rahulshah  The output of `sapply` is having row.names as 'Month'.  So, suppose, if `res <- sapply(...; data.frame(Month = row.names(res), res)`

Comment: I am trying this but couldn't work : `final_df<-sapply(lst, function(x) table(factor(nm1[x$ID], levels = as.character(sort(unique(nm1),data.frame(Month = row.names(lst), lst))))))`

Comment: @Rahulshah I meant `res <- sapply(lst, function(x) table(factor(nm1[x$ID], levels = as.character(unique(nm1))))); res1 <- data.frame(Month = row.names(res), res);row.names(res1) <- NULL`